# tool to show diagramatic representation of c code

Tags: c, flowchart

Is there any tool to show diagrammatic rep of flow of program if we input a C file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used [Visustin](http://www.aivosto.com/visustin.html) in the past

Answer (score 9):

For an open source workflow to do this, use [GNU cflow](http://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/) to generate a call graph in text format.  Then [Cflow2vcg](http://cflow2vcg.sourceforge.net/) can convert the output into an intermediate graph format that [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) can use to generate an image for you.

Answer (score 3):

http://code2flow.com allows you to create flowcharts from C-like pseudo code. It may be a bit similiar to Visustin but tries to create more good looking flowcharts and its approach is to allow to use natural language, although most of code will probably work unmodified as well. Click on the image to see the editor. Please note that I am involved in this solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to strictly be a graphical flow chart, [GNU cflow](http://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/sample.html) indicates the entire call tree for C source files.

Answer (score 0):

Software Blacksmiths has sold one commercially for a long time. I can't say much about it currently though -- it's probably a fair guess that the OS/2 version I used has been discontinued by now. [Software Blacksmiths](http://www.swbs.com/) still appears to be in business though -- a quick check turns up a web site anyway.

Glancing at the web site, it looks like relatively little has changed since I used it (even the OS/2 version still seems to be available). That being the case, I'd say it falls into the "fairly harmless" category, which is the best any flow charting tool can achieve.